# Why are decimals types base 10?

Tags: .net, vb.net, floating-point

I do not understand the terms Binary Floating Point and Decimal Floating point.  I know that Floats (32 Bit) and Doubles (64 bit) are binary floating points and Decimals (128 Bit) are Decimal Floating Points.  I understand that Decimals are base 10 and binaries are base 2.  However, I do not understand why decimals are base 10 as surely everything is base 2 in the end? Why are decimals base 10, rather than base 2 like floating points and doubles?

I have looked at many websites today e.g. this: [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1089026/1070452

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A floating-point number is made of a sign (+ or -), a significand and an exponent.
The significand is made of a number of base-B digits. The interpretation of the exponent e is that the number should be multiplied by B<sup>e</sup>. Choosing B as 2 or 10 does not make a difference for small integers (0, 1, 2, … can be represented exactly both in binary floating-point and in decimal floating-point) but the fractional numbers and the very large numbers that can be represented exactly are not the same in binary and decimal.

Examples: binary floating-point can represent 2<sup>-100</sup> and 2<sup>100</sup> exactly, but decimal128 cannot. Decimal floating-point can represent 0.1 exactly, but binary floating-point cannot (at any precision).

You are right that everything is binary in the end. A number of schemes are used to represent decimal floating-point as bits. The significand is the tricky part to encode. The IEEE standardisation committee devised [two schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point#IEEE_754-2008_encoding), one that is convenient for software and one that is convenient for hardware decoding. I do not know what .NET uses. It probably uses something similar to the “Binary integer significand field” technique from the IEEE 754 floating-point standard, where the allocated bits are used to encode, in binary, a number between 0 and B<sup>n</sup>-1, since this is what works best in software.

Comment: FWIW, .NET uses a 96 bit binary significand, a 5 bit decimal scale factor (they don't call it exponent) with valid values of 0..28 (28 stands for 10^-28) and a sign bit. This allows people to have a literal like `1.000m` and it will be stored as a `1000` significand with scale factor `3` (i.e. `10^-3`), i.e. preserving the decimals given.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: You can represent "simple" decimal numbers such as 0.1 exactly in a decimal representation, but only *approximately* in binary.

Typically the reason people use "decimal" types is for representing money, which usually comes in both large values and small fractions (100ths). A decimal type is best for keeping track of these types of numbers, and does not carry the risk of roundoff error producing results like 10.09999999999999.